# O float-right do bootstrap4 não funciona e o <nav> não estiliza

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Há algo que estou tentando arrumar já faz 5 horas e não consigo compreender o porque o `"float-rigth"` não funciona e nem mesmo o input. Na verdade minha tag `<nav>` não quer estilizar.

Detalhes: `<ul class="float-right">`Funcionou perfeitamente, mas o `<nav id="menu" class="float-right">` não quer estilizar nem que o saci pare de fumar.

Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Orlando City</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-Bfad6CLCknfcloXFOyFnlgtENryhrpZCe29RTifKEixXQZ38WheV+i/6YWSzkz3V" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <img id="logotipo" src="img/OrlandoLogo.png" alt="Logotipo">
        </div> <!-- Logo Orlando -->
        <div class="header-black">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="float-right">
                    <li class="club-01"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-02"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-03"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-04"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-05"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-06"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-07"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-08"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-09"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-10"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-11"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-12"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-13"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-14"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-15"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-16"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-17"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-18"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-19"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-20"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-21"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="club-22"><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Logo dos times -->
        <div class="container"> <!-- Menu de navegação -->
            <div class="row">
                <nav id="menu" class="float-right">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Tickets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="search" placeholder="search..." >
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </header>
    
    
    
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Chamando uma fonte */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open-Sans';
    src: url("../../fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
}

/* Header
-----------------*/
header {width: 100%;height: 150px;background-color: #5E299A;}
header .container{position: relative;}
header .header-black{background-color: black;height: 40px;width: 100%;display: inline-block}

/* Logo dos clubes */
header .header-black li{background-image: url("../../img/clubs.png.png");background-repeat: no-repeat;display: inline-block;margin:4px;}
header .header-black li.club-01{background-position: 0px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-02{background-position: -48px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-03{background-position: -94px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-04{background-position: -139px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-05{background-position: -189px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-06{background-position: -239px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-07{background-position: -288px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-08{background-position: -335px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-09{background-position: -380px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-10{background-position: -429px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-11{background-position: -479px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-12{background-position: -528px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-13{background-position: -578px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-14{background-position: -628px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-15{background-position: -674px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-16{background-position: -718px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-17{background-position: -761px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-18{background-position: -806px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-19{background-position: -855px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-20{background-position: -901px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-21{background-position: -948px 0px;}
header .header-black li.club-22{background-position: -996px 0px;}
header .header-black li a{width:32px;height:32px;display: block;}
header #logotipo{position: absolute;margin: 20px 2px;}

/* Links de navegação */
/* <-- gambiarra */
#menu li{display: inline-block;font-family: "Open-Sans";font-size: 1em;margin: -8px 25px;}
#menu li.search{width: 182px;}
#menu li.search ::webkit-input-placeholder{color: white;}
#menu li.search button{background: none;border: none;color: white;}
#menu li.search input{background-color: #5C2D90;border: none;}
#menu a{color: white;font-size: 16px;}
```

Agradeço desde já aos mestres.

Comment: Link da imagem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10ehXR4sZM1Mh4gNPw2svatHO4qyHQBor/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu objetivo não seria esse `justify-content-end`da uma olhada na [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/#horizontal-alignment).

Ajustei o código pra funcionar do jeito que você me pareceu querer. 
Quando for mexer com bootstrap deixe sempre uma guia aberta na documentação, ela é muito bem feita e vai te ajudar bastante.

removi esse seu link do bootstrap:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

e adicionei esse (é o que pedem pra usar pela documentação):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Removi uma div desnecessária, adicionei as classes das `li`'s e as classes certas no `nav`.

```html
<div class="container"> <!-- Menu de navegação -->
                <nav id="menu" class="nav justify-content-end">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Tickets</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">News</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="search" placeholder="search..." >
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        </div>
```

Esse código está funcionando mas se o que você quer é uma `navbar` e não uma `nav` qualquer eu acho que seria melhor pra você usar o [navbar do bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/). Tem mais coisas e é mais responsivo já que é feito pensando em ser uma barra de navegação principal. Da uma lida ai que você vai ver que tem bastante coisa legal nela.

Comment: Deu certo! Então nesse caso eu deveria usar ```class="nav justify-content-end"```. Obrigado. Mas uma dúvida, se eu usar esse link recomendado, não corre o risco deste template ficar obstruido futuramente, por conta das atualizações do bootstrap ?

Comment: Não, se você olhar o link pode ver ``/bootstrap/4.5.0/`` isso significa que se eles lançarem uma outra versão seu site vai se manter na 4.5.0, a não ser que você mude. Até o momento o bootstrap continua deixando as bibliotecas antigas disponíveis. Acho muito difícil de isso mudar mas caso aconteça vai ser uma noticia muito divulgada com certeza.

Comment: Pra usar a ``navbar`` vc tem que usar ``class=" navbar navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}"`` [como você pode ver aqui](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#how-it-works). Atualmente você está usando uma ``nav`` genérica, funciona mas não é o recomendado.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Só com essa pergunta eu pude ter a oportunidade de aprender bastante e agradeço-lhe por ter me dado o suporte. Quando me sobrar tempo, iri estudar mais a documentação do bootstrap!